# restart random number guessing game

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, random, restart

So far, I have created a game in python to guess a random number. It  works fine, but I want  to  create a reset button that will allow the user to guess one another time but  different number than the  first time. This is my code so far

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

randombroj=random.randint(0, 10)

def check():
   result=int(glvnes.get())            #the value of entry  widget
   if result==randombroj:
      gldugme.grid_forget()            #hide check button widget
      glvnes.grid_forget()             #hide entry widget

      bravo=tk.Label(root, text="Congratulations!!")      #congratulations widget
      bravo.config(width=40)
      bravo.grid(pady=0, row=1)

      def restart():       #restart function located in check function
         randombroj=random.randint(0, 10)      #get new random number
         bravo.destroy()                       #destroy congratulations widget
         weset.destroy()                       #destroy restart button
         gldugme.grid(pady=20, row=2)          #display again  check button
         glvnes.grid(pady=0, row=1)            #display again entry widget

      weset=tk.Button(root, text="Restart", font=("arial italic", 18), bg='#6BDF63', command=restart)                 #the restart button
      weset.config(width=13, heigh=2)
      weset.grid(pady=20, row=2)

root=tk.Tk()
root.title("Guess The  Secret Number")
root.geometry('450x250')
root.config(bg="#F2E06B")

glmeni=tk.Label(root, text="Can  you gess the secret number?", bg='#8CCEC0', font=("arial italic", 19))        #main  widget
glmeni.config(heigh=2)
glmeni.grid(pady=30, padx=28, row=0)

glvnes=tk.Entry(root, text="Enter number here:")       #entry box
glvnes.config(width=40)
glvnes.grid(pady=0, row=1)

gldugme=tk.Button(root, text="Check", font=("arial italic", 18), 
bg='#6BDF63', command=check)            #check button
gldugme.config(width=13, heigh=2)
gldugme.grid(pady=20, row=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Wnen you press the check button, if it is correct it will display  congratulations, and than the check  button is replaced with reset button. When  I click it, the entry widget and the  check button are reopening, but the random value  doesn't change. It stays as it was  the  first time. How do  I  fix it?

Comment: Do you mind adopting a better code layout? It just seems like the wrong way to proceed. `restart is never getting called unless restart gets called initially.

Comment: yes, I noted the problem and I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delete the last guess from the entry and declare `randomobroj` as global inside `restart()`:

```py
      def restart():       #restart function located in check function
         global randombroj
         glvnes.delete(0, "end")               # clear last guess
         ...
```